# Extension "IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML" not work on file .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I create project MVC.Net Core by VSCode and VSCode have extension "IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML". The problem is when I type class like "btn btn-primary" IntelliSense not show, I have to press Ctrl+Spacebar everytime when I type class.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to click Ctrl+Shift+P,and choose `cache css definitions`,and then click to cache it like this:
[image]